# How do I replace a background image using SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question, but I'm learning and I can't seem to find any help. Most of my experience is with storyboards, so SpriteKit is my first real foray into doing everything programatically.

I have a side-scrolling 2D game very similar to Flappy Bird. Every time the player hits a score of a multiple of, say 10, I need the background to change. The background is one image that is being slowly moved towards the left of the screen and replaced by itself.

The problem is that when it hits 10, I can't replace the image with another image. I've successfully added a new image on top of the old one using zPosition, but the original image is still underneath, and that seems clumsy and unstable.

I've tried to remove the original background image from the parent, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
var currentBg = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img/bgYellow.png")

func makeBackground() {

    let movebg = SKAction.moveByX(-currentBg.size().width, y: 0, duration: 9)
    let replacebg = SKAction.moveByX(currentBg.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0)
    let movebgForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([movebg, replacebg]))

    for var i:CGFloat=0; i<3; i++ {

        bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: currentBg)
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: currentBg.size().width/2 + currentBg.size().width * i, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        bg.size.height = self.frame.height
        bg.runAction(movebgForever)
        movingObjects.addChild(bg)

    }

}

 fun didMoveToView() {

      //Set up game, etc...

      makeBackground()

 }

if score == 10 {

      //I've tried adding the following line to remove the first image, but no luck
      //movingObjects.removeChildrenInArray([bg])          

      currentBg = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img/bgRed.png")
      makeBackground()

 } else if score == 20 {

      currentBg = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img/bgBlue.png")
      makeBackground()

 } //Else etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing texture not your `background` node texture.

```
var background: SKSpriteNode!
```

Then you need to create your background

```
    background = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "img/bgYellow.png"), color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(world.frame.size.width, world.frame.size.height))
    background.position = CGPointMake(world.frame.size.width / 2, world.frame.size.height / 2)
    // etc
```

To change your background image:

```
if score == 10 {

    background.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img/bgRed.png")
    makeBackground()
}
```